# Auto hide ubuntu-budgie panel

Tags: panel, budgie, ubuntu-budgie

Is there any way to make the ubuntu-budgie top panel auto hide ?

I like that desktop environnement a lot, but there is a lot of lost screen space when an application is maximized (an app like chromium).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the budgie 10.x series there is not a way to autohide the top-panel.

If vertical screen estate is your key issue then I would suggest you checkout `budgie-pixel-saver-applet`.  It is available in the 17.04 backports repository.  For non CSD apps - the top-bar in maximized apps like chromium are combined with the top-panel.

[image]

Backports can be enabled through the welcome application - it is in the Recommendations part of the app.

Answer (score 2):

- Search for budgie applet and click on it
- Go to Budgie Desktop Settings. There you should see a a thing called Panels.
- Click on Top Dock below "Panels".
- Then at the top you'll see "Applets" and "settings".
- Click on settings. This is the top dock settings.

You can now change position, make it hide automatically, etc.